# Why are class-validator decorators removing properties when used with class-transformer

Tags: next.js, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm trying to use class-validator and class-transformer to perform validation on API requests in a Next.js API route.

I've put together this basic API handler to demonstrate:

```js
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

class PostBody {
  @IsString()
  public title!: string;

  public content!: string;
}

const validateRequest = (req: NextApiRequest) => {
  const request = plainToInstance(PostBody, req.body);

  console.log(request);
};

const Handler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  validateRequest(req);
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'ok' });
};

export default Handler;
```

If I send a request using postman with body:

```
{ "title": "Test", "content": "Hello world" }
```

This is logged to the console:
`PostBody { content: 'Hello world' }`

If I remove the `@IsString()` decorator, this gets logged: `PostBody { title: 'Test', content: 'Hello world' }`.

Anyone got any ideas on why the class-validator decorators seem to be removing properties?

Using:

```
"next": "^12.1.0",
"class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
"class-validator": "^0.13.2",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that your babel is not configured properly.

Try to put this into your `babel.config.js` (create the file if you don’t have it already):

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['next/babel'],
  plugins: [['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { 'legacy': true }]],
};
```

Also don’t forget to put these two `devDependencies` into your `package.json`:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.17.8",
```

And for typescript these two lines into your `tsconfig.json`

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

Comment: I've marked this answer as correct because it is, technically, correct. However, I was using the new SWC compiler from nextjs which currently doesn't fully support these experimental decorators fully.